# String patterns in Java

Tags: java, replace

Okay, let's say I have a string like this:

```
String strExample = "name=\"bob\" age=\"25\" salary=\"$500 per month\"";
```

I want to get rid of anything that's in between the ' "" ' characters (the '\"\"' ones).

I've been trying to use this:

```
String newStr = strExample.replaceAll("=\"[ ]*\"", "");
```

The problem is, I can't figure out what to put in the '[ ]' part to get rid of what's in quotations.  All I can ever get returned is:

```
name
```

What should I do to get the newStr to return:

```
name age salary
```

I cannot use an XML parser as the requirements for what I'm doing don't allow me to.

Comment: does this come from xml?

Comment: then why are you not using an xml parser?

Comment: @jlordo: Requirements don't allow me to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String strExample = "name=\"bob\" age=\"25\" salary=\"$500 per month\"";
strExample = strExample.replaceAll("=\".+?\"", "");
System.out.print(strExample);
```

will work,

But as others have said XML parser will be better

Edit:

To explain my answer a little more. the "key" part is the "?" which stops regex from being greedy and matching as much as possible.

[More info here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

Comment: Thank you for giving me an answer.  I realize the XML parser is better, but I simply can't use it.  I have reasons I can't state why.